# Drag & Drop : Cursor in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

My problem is that in Chrome the cursor doesn't move with the draggable item. It works fine in IE.
I have jquery and jquery-ui 1.11.1 and this the script I am using

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}


function drag(ev) {
    ev.target.innerHTML += ' '; // Add space so that there is no kerning...
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.parentNode.replaceChild(document.getElementById(data), ev.target);
    document.getElementById(data).className = " ";
}

function drop(ev)
    {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

      if(ev.target.getAttribute('data-drop') == data)
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    }
```

Maybe something is missing. Help would really be appreciated

Comment: in my experience the cursor moved correctly in chrome, please create a jsfiddle or codepen about it.

Comment: Thanks Luizgrs for the speedy reply. I am not familiar with creating jsfiddle but this is what I have done. Hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/8hwh7pkt/

Comment: Thanks Luizgrs. I'm not familiar with creating jsfiddle but this is what I have done. Hope it helps. Thanks once again. http://jsfiddle.net/8hwh7pkt/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the drag image ('shadow') being moved to the corner of the `#word`, correct?

It looks like Chrome is calculating the position wrong, may be because the `<span>` and `<center>` tags, I guess...

You can fix that using the `setDragImage` method, set the DragImage to be the `target` of the event and set the offset according to the click position, this will force Chrome to render it right:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.target.innerHTML += ' '; // Add space so that there is no kerning...
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);

    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, ev.layerX - ev.target.offsetLeft, ev.layerY - ev.target.offsetTop);
}
```

It's working here http://jsfiddle.net/wv19zzsd/5/

(In my fiddle I changed the Type to 'text/plain' only to test if that was the cause of the issue, but it is not)

Comment: Thanks Luizgrs. Done and works. Thank you very much. really appreciate the quick help. Magic.